# How to securely connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

How do I connect to the database on Cloud SQL without having to add my credentials file inside the container?

Comment: Note that Cloud SQL will soon be officially supported by Cloud Run. It will not require to install the Cloud SQL proxy inside the container.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UPDATE:** to connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run see the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connect-cloudsql)

---

Cloud SQL is now supported by the fully managed version of Cloud Run (Cloud Run on GKE users were already able to use Cloud SQL using a private IP)

To get started:

- if you do not have one already, [create a Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance).
- make sure that the [Cloud SQL admin API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com) is enabled
- deploy a new revision of your Cloud Run service with gcloud alpha and the following flag:
  `$ gcloud run services update --add-cloudsql-instances [INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]`
  Where is `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` is of the type `project:region:instancename`.

When you do this, Cloud Run will activate and configure the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) for you. You should then connect to it via the `/cloudsql/[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]` Unix socket.

Comment: This actually does not work. The syntax does not match the CLI. However, after the first successful update all subsequent updates crash gcloud `gcloud alpha run services update wordpress2 --add-cloudsql-instances cloudrun-sql` with the error: `{"version": "0.0.1", "verbosity": "ERROR", "timestamp": "2019-04-30T06:09:07.382Z", "message": "gcloud crashed (TypeError): can only join an iterable"}`

Comment: Note. For those interested I have WordPress now working in Cloud Run. I plan to document this as soon as Cloud SQL is working correctly with Cloud Run.

Comment: The crash is solved by changing the gcloud command to: `gcloud alpha run services update wordpress2 --set-cloudsql-instances cloudrun-sql`

Comment: However, using `--add-cloudsql-instances` should not crash gcloud.

Comment: Worth noting this is explained in the official documentation at Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connect-cloudsql.

Comment: My Cloud SQL instance is outside us-central1, I have followed the instructions (gcloud beta run deploy --image [IMAGE] --add-cloudsql-instances [CONNECTION-NAME]) but there is no /cloudsql directory. I have also tried --set-cloudsql-instances cloudrun-sql as per @john-hanley

Comment: The automatic setup does not work for me.  I can see the `/cloudsql` mount (`none on /cloudsql type 9p (rw)`) but there's nothing in there.

If I install `cloud_sql_proxy` and manually run `cloud_sql_proxy -instances="[CONNECTION-NAME]" -dir=/tmp` , then the socket is there in `/tmp`.

Comment: The `--add-cloudsql-instances` works fine for me. Please ensure gcloud is up to date and open an issue at https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers with exact reproduction steps.

Comment: I was also successfully able to connect to a Cloud SQL instance in another region. Please provide exact reproduction steps and code sample in a new StackOverflow question

Comment: Does this support the postgres IAM integration?

Answer (score 3):

## CONNECTING FROM CLOUD RUN (fully managed) TO CLOUD SQL USING UNIX DOMAIN SOCKETS (Java)

> At this time Cloud Run (fully managed) does not support connecting to
>   the Cloud SQL instance using TCP. Your code should not try to access the instance
>   using an IP address such as 127.0.0.1 or 172.17.0.1.
>   [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run)

1.[Install and initialize the Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/?authuser=1)

2.Update components:

```
gcloud components update
```

3.Create a new project

```
gcloud projects create run-to-sql
gcloud config set project run-to-sql
gcloud projects describe run-to-sql
```

4.Enable billing

```
gcloud alpha billing projects link  run-to-sql --billing-account  XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX
```

5.Set the compute project-info metadata:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --project run-to-sql
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata google-compute-default-region=europe-west2,google-compute-default-zone=europe-west2-b
```

6.Enable the Cloud SQL Admin API:

```
 gcloud services enable sqladmin.googleapis.com
```

7.Create a Cloud SQL instance with public Ip

```
#Create the sql instance in the same region as App Engine Application
gcloud --project=run-to-sql beta sql instances create database-external --region=europe-west2
#Set the password for the "root@%" MySQL user:
gcloud sql users set-password root --host=% --instance database-external --password root 
#Create a user
gcloud sql users create user_name --host=% --instance=database-external  --password=user_password
#Create a database
gcloud sql databases create user_database --instance=database-external
gcloud sql databases list --instance=database-external
gcloud sql instances list
```

> Cloud Run (fully managed) uses a service account to authorize your
>   connections to Cloud SQL. This service account must have the correct
>   IAM permissions to successfully connect. Unless otherwise configured,
>   the default service account is in the format
>   PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com.

8.Ensure that the service account for your service has one of the following IAM roles:Cloud SQL Client (preferred)

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding run-to-sql --member serviceAccount:PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. --role roles/cloudsql.client
```

9.Clone the java-docs-repository

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples.git
cd java-docs-samples/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet/
ls
#Dockerfile  pom.xml  README.md  src
```

10.Inspect the file that handle the connection to Cloud SQL

```
 cat src/main/java/com/example/cloudsql/ConnectionPoolContextListener.java
```

11.Containerizing the app and uploading it to Container Registry

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/run-to-sql/run-mysql
```

12.Deploy the service to Cloud Run

```
gcloud run deploy run-mysql --image gcr.io/run-to-sql/run-mysql
```

13.Configure the service for use with Cloud Run

```
gcloud run services update run-mysql --add-cloudsql-instances run-to-sql:europe-west2:database-external --set-env-vars CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME=run-to-sql:europe-west2:database-external  DB_USER=user_name,DB_PASS=user_password,DB_NAME=user_database
```

14.Test it

```
 curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"   https://run-mysql-xxxxxxxx-xx.x.run.app
```

SUCCESS!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue with connecting from a dockerized FastApi application to CloudSQL via private ip. I took the following 3 steps to resolve my issue:

1. Ensure your application is utilizing the proper `database-connection-string`.

   - *Sanity check, always do this first. You don't want to spend hours researching a solution without first ruling out a wrong connection string.*
   - ***When testing (and only when testing):*** consider logging the db connection string on app init so you can explicitly confirm your connection string is correct.
2. Provide the `Cloud SQL Client` role to my cloudrun default service account.

   - *Contains the following permissions:*
     `cloudsql.instances.connect`
     `cloudsql.instances.get`
3. Create a `VPC connector` within the network of the database ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc)). And assign the VPC connector to the Cloud Run service.

Comment: I configured this a few weeks back and noticed that the VPC Connector was charging me.  Is there a way to do this without the VPC connector?  Have you noticed some costs for the VPC connector?