# How can I run WordPress on Google Cloud Platform Cloud Run?

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, bitnami, google-cloud-run

According to https://cloud.google.com/wordpress/ this are the to Google Cloud Platform's hosting options for WordPress so far. But I think Cloud Run is the best option for no tech person. However in order to run WordPress in Cloud Run the application should be containerized.
Using the VM with Bitnami WordPress involves technical details and management which I don't want to deal with. On the other hand WordPress in App Engine Standard is doing a similar job like Cloud Run, but with some differences. Which one is better: WordPress on App Engine vs. WordPress on Cloud Run? If cloud run is much better. How?

Comment: noticed that i found out that cloud run requiring             
        https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#how-do-i-make-my-web-application-compatible-with-cloud-ru  
Your existing applications must listen on PORT environment variable to work on Cloud Run (see container contract). (This value is currently only 8080, but it may change in the future.)

Comment: on the hand wordpress HTTP is Usually for HTTP URLs, Port 80 of the web server is used, which Apache2 and all web server software opens normally after the installation. HTTPS requires extra Apache Modules (mod_ssl) to be enabled, port 443 to be opened, properly configured, other settings including VirtualHost configuration to be properly configured.  https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

This was asked before: [How to run WordPress on Google Cloud Run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796876/how-to-run-wordpress-on-google-cloud-run)

Also check out:

- https://medium.com/@salvopappalardo/how-to-install-a-wordpress-site-on-google-cloud-run-828bdc0d0e96
- https://github.com/acadevmy/cloud-run-
- https://github.com/xantrix/cloud-run-wordpress

Comment: In order to complement this correct answer (it only addresses the How? part) and address the "is it better to host on App Engine or Cloud Run" part I would like to add that given the current state of affairs and nature of the application hosting WordPress in App Engine (please check this [example](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible)) would be a better architectural choice than using Cloud Run. Please refer to @AhmetB great insights on the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796876/how-to-run-wordpress-on-google-cloud-run) he mentions.

Answer (score 0):

For a non tech person, I'd suggest Googles [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/) which uses the same containerized technology in the background, but is a service managed by Google similar to other hosting providers.