# Connecting to a Google Cloud SQL instance from a Google Cloud Run docker image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Google Cloud Run docker image and would like to connect to a Cloud SQL instance. The instance has a private IP, but I don't seem to be able to use that.

Is this scenario supported for Cloud Run, and how do I connect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "[Connecting to GCP services](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-gcp-services#services_not_yet_supported)":

> The following table lists services that are not yet supported by Cloud Run (however, they are supported by Cloud Run on GKE):
>
> - Cloud SQL
> - Cloud Endpoints
> - Virtual Private Cloud
> - Cloud Memorystore
> - Cloud Load Balancing
> - Cloud Filestore

Most of these are due to Cloud Run currently lacking a VPC connector, however this is in progress and will eventually be available.

Comment: Right. So no workarounds ? Would I be able to use a public IP while VPC is added ?

Comment: Yes, using the Public IP should work fine, with the tradeoff that your database now has a public IP.

Comment: Cloud SQL is now supported, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693241/how-to-securely-connect-to-cloud-sql-from-cloud-run for the answer